Как обратиться к элементу src в python selenium?
При использовании Xpath выдает ошибку что не удается найти, ошибка появляется из-за того что при каждом запуске новый xpath. Как еще можно найти нужный элемент на странице и обратиться к нему?
<img src="data:image/gif;base58,TH0klTYHED/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander">
Пробовал через CSS_SELECTOR получаю ошибку TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Не понятно что именно не так и как обращаться к таким элементам
Пробую таким способом: button_data = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[class=' x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander']").click()

Как вы пытаетесь получить элемент через CSS_SELECTOR? Приведите код. (В документации так: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "СЕЛЕКТОР"))

Пробую таким способом: button_data = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[class=' x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander']").click()

Приведите ваш код, и подробно опишите проблему, тогда мы вам поможем.
